# Jest component which passes functions as prop

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test my item component, but it contains the function isLoading() as prop. I call this function in my component to set a state in the parent (container). When I try to mount it, then jest throws the error TypeError: this.props.isLoading is not a function.

```
//Container.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';

class Container extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
    };

  changeIsLoading(bool) {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: bool,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Item
          className="item"
          isLoading={this.changeIsLoading}
          styles={this.props.styles}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}


// Item.test.js
import React from 'react';
import Container from '../containers/Container';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import changeIsLoading from '../containers/Container';

describe('Container', () => {
    const tree = mount(
      <Item
        isLoading={changeIsLoading(false)}
        styles={style}
      />
    );
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to the fact that you are not passing a function in your test.

```
  <Item
    isLoading={changeIsLoading(false)}
    styles={style}
  />
```

You are passing the result of calling `changeIsLoading(false)`.

Whatever value it returns, it will be the value that the Item component will try to call as `this.props.isLoading()`.

And it will fail, because `this.props.isLoading` is not a function, it is what `changeIsLoading(false)` returned.

What you probably want to do is to pass `changeIsLoading` as `isLoading` prop to Item component.

```
  <Item
    isLoading={changeIsLoading}
    styles={style}
  />
```